# How do I shorten my if statements in c sharp?

Tags: c#, if-statement, console

I'm trying to make a metric system converter where you input a number, the unit of measurement and the desired output unit (what to convert it to), and I also separated the converter as a different method.

The program takes the input and the only thing I can think of how to convert it is by converting the given number back to meter by dividing the input number by the original unit that is equivalent to 1 mile then multiply it by the desired output unit that is equivalent to 1 meter.

```
double m_Out = 1;  // These are all equivalent to 1 meter        //meter
double mm_Out = 1000;                                            //millimeters
double cm_Out = 100;                                             //centimeters
double mi_Out = 0.000621371192;                                  //miles
double in_Out = 39.3700787;                                      //inches
double km_Out = 0.001;                                           //kilometers
double ft_Out = 3.2808399;                                       //feet
double yd_Out = 1.0936133;                                       //yard
```

I am also using a 'double' variable type to prevent exceptions when an input number has a decimal.

I'm wondering if there is another way of doing it other than long lines of if statements. Currently I'm using multiple if statements to check what the input unit is so that we know what unit it is and what to do with it then goes to another if statement to see what the desired output unit is.

This is the code I'm going for now:

```
using System;

namespace num4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Converter(double firstNum, string firstUnit, string unitOut)
        {
            double m_Out = 1;
            double mm_Out = 1000;
            double cm_Out = 100;
            double mi_Out = 0.000621371192;
            double in_Out = 39.3700787;
            double km_Out = 0.001;
            double ft_Out = 3.2808399;
            double yd_Out = 1.0936133;

            //convert input back to miles (dividing by its own unit value equivalent to 1 mile) before comverting to desired output unit

            string errornotfound = "Input Unit is not recognized, make sure the units are found on the given list.";

            if (firstUnit == "m") //                                                                    if the input is m
            {
                string unit = "m";
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = firstNum * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            } 
            else if (firstUnit == "mm") //                                                            If the input is mm
            {
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            }
            else if (firstUnit == "cm")
            {
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / cm_Out) * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / cm_Out) * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / cm_Out) * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / cm_Out) * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / cm_Out) * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / cm_Out) * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / cm_Out) * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mm_Out) * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            }
            else if (firstUnit == "mi")
            {
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / mi_Out) * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            }
            else if (firstUnit == "in")
            {
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / in_Out) * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            }
            else if (firstUnit == "km")
            {
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / km_Out) * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            }
            else if (firstUnit == "ft")
            {
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / ft_Out) * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            }
            else if (firstUnit == "yd")
            {
                if (unitOut == "mm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * mm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "m")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * m_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "cm")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * cm_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "mi")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * mi_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "in")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * in_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "km")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * km_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "ft")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * ft_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else if (unitOut == "yd")
                {
                    double res = (firstNum / yd_Out) * yd_Out;
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(errornotfound);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*Metric Converter
             * Write a program that can convert a given input distance between 8 units of measurement
             * [m,mm,cm,mi,in,km,ft,yd]
             * 
             * 
             * input
             * '''
             * meter(m)
             * 
             * sample input
             * '''m
             * number to convert (6)a
             * type of unit (km)
             * output unit to convert to (ft)r
             * [6km >> ???ft]k
             * -----------------------------
             * start
             * input for num1
             * input for unit1
             * input for out_uni1
             * convert unit>>>>out_uni1
             * print out_uni1
             * end
             * -----------------------------
             */
            string border = "--------------------------------------------------------------";
            Console.WriteLine(border);
            Console.WriteLine("                      Metric Converter");
            Console.WriteLine(border);
           
            Console.Write("What number would you like to convert? ");
            double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(border);
            Console.WriteLine("Units: [m], [mm], [cm], [mi], [in], [km], [ft], [yd]");
            Console.WriteLine(border);
            Console.Write("What is the original unit? ");
            string inputUnit = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("What unit would you like to convert it to? ");
            string inputOutUnit = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(border);
            Console.Write("The result is: ");
            Converter(num1, inputUnit, inputOutUnit);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Freely add your suggestions as I would like to hear alternatives.

```
            /*Metric Converter
         * Write a program that can convert a given input distance between 8 units of measurement
         * [m,mm,cm,mi,in,km,ft,yd]
         * 
         * 
         * input
         * '''
         * meter(m)
         * 
         * sample input
         * '''
         * number to convert (6)
         * type of unit (km)
         * output unit to convert to (ft)
         * [6km >> ???ft]
         * -----------------------------mjgs
         * start
         * input for num1
         * input for unit1
         * input for out_uni1
         * convert unit>>>>out_uni1
         * print out_uni1
         * end
         * -----------------------------mjgs
         */
```

Comment: Using switch-case would shorten the code but still the logic requires some repeated code anyway.

Comment: You don't need any `if` statements at all. Use a `Dictionary<string, double>` to store each unit as a key and the conversion factor to a standard unit - probably meters - as the value. You then simply feed your unit inputs into the dictionary to get the two conversion factors and multiply by one and divide by the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C#8 or above, you can use the new switch expression to shorten this significantly. The above code would then become:

```cs
static void Converter ( double firstNum, string firstUnit, string unitOut )
{
    //convert input back to miles (dividing by its own unit value equivalent to 1 mile) before comverting to desired output unit

    string errornotfound = "Input Unit is not recognized, make sure the units are found on the given list.";

    try
    {
        var result = firstNum / UnitValue( firstUnit ) * UnitValue( unitOut );
        Console.WriteLine ( result );
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine ( errornotfound );
    }

    double UnitValue ( string unit) => unit switch
    {
        "m" => 1,
        "mm" => 1000,
        "cm" => 100,
        "mi" => 0.000621371192,
        "in" => 39.3700787,
        "km" => 0.001,
        "ft" => 3.2808399,
        "yd" => 1.0936133,
        _ => throw new ArgumentException ( "Unkown unit type." )
    };
}
```

*Please note*: I'm only answering the question "How do I shorten my if statements in c sharp?" by using a switch expression. I haven't commented on whether this is the best method or not. I've also used a local method as well, but that could be extracted from the `Converter` method.

UPDATE: as per the comment by @jmcilhinney, a Dictionary<string, double> would reduce the code as well:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    const string NOTFOUND = "Input Unit is not recognized, make sure the units are found on the given list.";

    private static Dictionary<string, double> values = new Dictionary<string, double>
    {
        ["m"] = 1,
        ["mm"] = 1000,
        ["cm"] = 100,
        ["mi"] = 0.000621371192,
        ["in"] = 39.3700787,
        ["km"] = 0.001,
        ["ft"] = 3.2808399,
        ["yd"] = 1.0936133,
    };

    static string Converter ( double firstNum, string firstUnit, string unitOut )
    {
        //convert input back to miles (dividing by its own unit value equivalent to 1 mile) before comverting to desired output unit

        if ( !values.TryGetValue ( firstUnit, out var value ) )
            return NOTFOUND;

        var firstCalculation = firstNum / value;

        if ( !values.TryGetValue ( unitOut, out value ) )
            return NOTFOUND;

        return ( firstCalculation * value ).ToString ( );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It is not always a multiplication operation and it is different for different situations

Comment: @hosseinsabziani I'm looking at the OP code again, and unless I'm mistaken, each iteration is of the form result = firstNumber / firstUnit * unitOut.

Comment: This answer by @Milanegonvotrubec is the most compact and solves your issue WITHOUT if statements. If you look at your original code, you are repeating yourself multiple multiple multiple times and we always want to adhere by the DRY principal ... Don't Repeat Yourself. This solution is elegant and efficient. If you don't like the dictionary approach, then stick with the calls to the method with the switch statement. Both approaches end up giving you the same result (although in his 2nd solution Converter is returning a string instead of writing it to the console directly).

Comment: thank you so much I'll try looking for other ways as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do switch case on it.

```
switch (firstUnit)
            {
                case "m":
                    switch (unit)
                    {
                        case "mm":
                            res = 0.0;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "mm":
                    switch (unit)
                    {
                        case "cm":
                            res = 1.0;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define enum

```
enum Unit
{
    Meter,
    Millimetre,
    Centimeter,
    Mile,
    Inch,
    Kilometer,
    Foot,
    Yard
}
```

Extend its functionality

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static double InMeters(this Unit unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case Unit.Meter:
                return 1;
            case Unit.Millimetre:
                return 0.001;
            case Unit.Centimeter:
                return 0.01;
            case Unit.Mile:
                return 1609.34;
            case Unit.Inch:
                return 0.0254;
            case Unit.Kilometer:
                return 1_000;
            case Unit.Foot:
                return 0.3048;
            case Unit.Yard:
                return 0.9144;
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

Then use

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double value = 100;
    Unit inUnit = Unit.Centimeter;
    Unit outUnit = Unit.Meter;
    var result = value * inUnit.InMeters() / outUnit.InMeters();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```